# React set styles on Body

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can i add styles for the HTML Body in the react functional component. I have included this in the css. I see other css are getting applied. but body styles are missing

```
body { 
  height: 100% ;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[image]

Comment: how do you import the css?

Comment: Why do you need to style the body ? can't we simply add style for the main container in functional component?

Comment: including like this `import './App.module.css';`

Comment: They HTML body styling was inconsistent with react component so i want to update it

Answer (score 0):

you can add this styles in `public/index.html`

You also forgot to add colon after body in css.

#### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <style>
       body:{ 
          height: 100% ;
          display:flex;
          flex-direction:column;
          justify-content: center;
       }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are using style tag .so use `body{css style}` instead of `body:{}` .Object style only perform inside the react dom

Comment: @Ferin Thanks for your answer, but It is not getting applied

Comment: while initial load  the style was there for fraction of second , but i think react is removing them after that

Comment: Try adding css in index.css file